# "\ifthenelse" in minipage or tabular with "\\" in command argument

Tags: tables, ifthenelse

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coreitem}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{#1 \\}%
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{#2 \\}%
    #1
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\\ %
    \raggedright{#3}}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
}
\coreitem{one \\ one 2}{two -- two 2}{tres -- tres 2}  % successful
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

This is the first attempt of using `\coreitem`: it has `\\` in the first argument which involves an `\ifthenelse` test and it compiles fine.

The second attempt is as follows:

```
\coreitem{one \\ one 2}{two \\ two 2}{tres -- tres 2}  % failing
```

Here the only difference is the replacement of `--` with `\\` in the second argument. It involves an `\ifthenelse` test within the `tabular` and it fails at compiling. Here is the error:

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                 \par 
l.23 ...item{one \\ one 2}{two \\ two 2}{tres -- tres 2}  % failing
```

In the third attempts :

```
\coreitem{one \\ one 2}{two -- two 2}{tres \\ tres 2}  % failing
```

Here the change compare to the first and successful attempt is the replacement of the `--` with `\\` in the third argument, i.e. involving an `\ifthenelse` within the `minipage` which is itself within the `tabular`. It is failing at compiling and produces the following error:

```
...
! Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.23 ...m{one -- one 2}{two -- two 2}{tres \\ tres 2}
```

---

### shortened version of the failing code with the same error

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coreitem}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{#1 \\}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{#2 \\}
  \end{minipage}
}
\noindent
\coreitem{one \\ one 2}{two \\ two 2}  % error
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

### here is the piece of code exhibiting a problem for one of the answers

`\MyIfEmptyF` is printing the `\\` of its second argument if present even when the reference in the first argument is empty :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyIfEmptyF}[1]{
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coreitem}[1][2em]{
  \def\coreitem@arg@i{#1}
  \@ifnextchar[{\coreitem@i}{\coreitem@i[{2em}]}
}

\def\coreitem@i[#1]{
  \def\coreitem@arg@ii{#1}
  \@ifnextchar[{\coreitem@ii}{\coreitem@ii[{0.2em}]}
}

\def\coreitem@ii[#1]#2#3{
  \def\coreitem@arg@iii{#1}
  \def\coreitem@arg@iv{#2}
  \def\coreitem@arg@v{#3}
  \coreitem@iii
}

\def\coreitem@iii#1{
  \def\coreitem@arg@vi{#1}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \MyIfEmptyF{\coreitem@arg@iv}{
      \coreitem@arg@iv}
    \MyIfEmptyF{\coreitem@arg@vi}{\\}
    \MyIfEmptyF{\coreitem@arg@vi}{\\}
    \coreitem@arg@v
  \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\noindent
\coreitem{one -- one 2}{two --- two 2}{}
\end{document}
```

Note that the problem is seen if there are at least two consecutive `\MyIfEmptyF...` satisfying the condition i stated above. Then the number of `\\` printed is n - 1, n being the number of consecutive `\MyIfEmptyF...`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) For me your first example which should have worked doesn't. It fails with a "there is no line to end here"-error.

Comment: you have `\\     \raggedright{#3}` at the start of the minipage. the `\\ `  at the start of a paragraph will always generate an error and `\raggedright` does not take a `{}` argument so this can be simply `\raggedright #3` there is no need for a test, if `#3` is empty this does nothing anyway.

Comment: @Skillmon : indeed i also get the same error as you states when testing the code i posted. Actually before submitting it I removed some bits I was sure they would not affect the problem. Actually in the original code there was "#3" within the minipage just before the \ifthenelse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

etoolbox package commands seem to be more robust than ifthen's. Here \ifstrequal and \ifdefempty seem to be fine as a replacement of \ifthenelse.
The following example is using \ifstrequal. But it does not seem to work for arguments like \myfunc@arg@iv, \myfunc@arg@v, ... Where \ifdefempty comes into the field. The second example is using the latter. The example shows the use of \ifdefempty in a tabular but it works even in a minipage within a tabular.

### solution for simple commands :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coreitem}[3]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{#1 \\}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{#2 \\}
  \end{minipage}
}
\noindent
\coreitem{one \\ one 2}{two \\ two 2}  % error
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

### solution for complex commands :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coreitem}[1][2em]{%
  \def\coreitem@arg@i{#1}
  \@ifnextchar[{\coreitem@i}{\coreitem@i[{2em}]}
}

\def\coreitem@i[#1]{%
  \def\coreitem@arg@ii{#1}
  \@ifnextchar[{\coreitem@ii}{\coreitem@ii[{0.2em}]}
}

\def\coreitem@ii[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\coreitem@arg@iii{#1}
  \def\coreitem@arg@iv{#2}
  \def\coreitem@arg@v{#3}
  \coreitem@iii
}

\def\coreitem@iii#1{%
  \def\coreitem@arg@vi{#1}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \ifdefempty{\coreitem@arg@iv}{}{%
      \coreitem@arg@iv \\}
    \ifdefempty{\coreitem@arg@vi}{}{\\}
    \ifdefempty{\coreitem@arg@vi}{}{\\}
    \coreitem@arg@v
  \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\noindent
\coreitem{one \\ one 2}{two --- two 2}{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within the nature of `tabular` cells. Those cells are an environment and because of that the arguments which contain contents for different tabular cells to `\ifthen` are failing. This is true for argument `#2` and `#3` but not for `#1` and because of that `\\` is working in the first argument.

Note, that I'm entirely insecure about the above and it's just a wild guess.

The following however does work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MyIfEmptyF}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
    \expandafter\@gobble%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@firstofone%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\CoreItem}[3]{%
  \MyIfEmptyF{#1}{#1\\}%
  \begin{tabular}{l}%
    \MyIfEmptyF{#2}{#2\\}%
    \MyIfEmptyF{#1}{#1\\}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \raggedright #3%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\CoreItem{one -- one 2}{two -- two 2}{tres -- tres 2}  % successful
\CoreItem{one \\ one 2}{two -- two 2}{tres -- tres 2}  % successful
\CoreItem{one -- one 2}{two \\ two 2}{tres -- tres 2}  % successful
\CoreItem{one -- one 2}{two -- two 2}{tres \\ tres 2}  % successful

\end{document}
```

Comment: this looks good. I tested it, and even by putting the \MyIfEmptyF within the minipage and it worked. But not with the \raggedright.

Comment: @user1850133 what did not work with the `\raggedright`? Is the text not correctly justified or did you put the `\raggedright` into the second argument to `\MyIfEmptyF`?

Comment: @user1850133 for me `\raggedright` works fine. I don't understand where your issue lies, could you update your question?

Comment: actually it's not \raggedright, at least it doesn't seem. I usually put a newline statement at the beginning of arguments, so in the command declaration I leave the first argument call with no "\\" and for all others I put "\\ #n". Here in the minipage I get "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end." if I \MyIfEmptyF{#3}{\\ #3}.

Comment: You'd have to insert the `\\ ` prior to the `minipage` based on the contents of `#3` so the call should be `\MyIfEmptyF{#3}{\\}\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\raggedright #3\end{minipage}` or `\MyIfEmptyF{#3}{\\\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\raggedright #3\end{minipage}}`. The issue is, that in the `minipage` the contents start with a new paragraph, which can't start with a newline.

Comment: right, it works well like that.

Comment: @user1850133 if it solves your problem you should upvote (and maybe accept) my answer!

Comment: not yet... actually for the code extract I posted here I cleared out as much as I could to expose the problematic point from my actual .tex file which is much bigger and in that file your \MyIfEmptyF command is leading to a weird problem. It actually inserts the "\\" when it exists in the command's second argument even when the corresponding field is empty. If the second argument does not contain any "\\" either at the beggining or at the end it does not output any newline if the corresponding field is empty. The \ifthenelse command was fine on this matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66963/discussion-between-user1850133-and-skillmon).